# How to look for possible strings in a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsarray, sql-like

I have a `NSArray` of `NSStrings`, and what I want to do is for example looking for the 8-characters strings with a R as the first char and a A as the third one.

In SQL I would do like this :

```
SELECT string FROM array WHERE string LIKE 'R*A*****';
```

But I've no idea of what's the best way to do so in Obj-C. Of course I could create a function checking the chars with `characterAtIndex:` but I'm sure there are some faster ways to proceed like regexes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think a regular expression would be faster?

Comment: It was just a guess, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably just to use [`indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a), and define a block that just checks the two characters you care about.  Something like:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (([obj length] == 8) &&
            ([obj characterAtIndex:0] == 'R') &&
            ([obj characterAtIndex:2] == 'A'))
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness: A pattern matching approach
that resembles the SQL query is

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE %@", @"R?A?????"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But a quick test showed that the block-based filtering as in Carl's answer is much faster,
at least in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using characterAtIndex is the easiest choice,but if u really want to use regex pattern matching then probably this pattern will help.

```
 for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)       //'array' is the nsarray with collection of strings
{
    string = [array objectAtIndex:i];    //'string' takes each string from the array
    NSRegularExpression* reg=[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"R[a-zA-Z]{1}A[a-zA-Z]{5}" options:0 error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match=[reg firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    NSLog(@"result is %@",[string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]]);             


}
```

Hope it Helps!!!